# how to split the text in the cell of table

Tags: tables, text, split, cell

I need to split the text in the cell.
I have tried the `\par` but this command doesn't work inside the brackets `{ }`. My attempt is below.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Caption}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|} {\textbf{Title1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\textbf{Title2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\textbf{Title3}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{text text text text} & text text text  text  text & text text text text text text text text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & text text text text text & text text text text text text text text text text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text text } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & связях text text text text & text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text }   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & text text text & text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ text text text } & text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text …} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|} {text text  texttexttext \par texttexttext} & texttexttext \par texttexttext texttexttexttext & texttexttexttext texttexttexttext \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You've got `\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}...` which will give you a `4cm` wide cell in which lines will break, but then for some reason you then have `\multicolumn{1}{|l|} {` with an `l` column type instead of a `p` column type which completely overrides it and produces a cell which won't break lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\multicolumn{1}{l}` spoils your try. Please see the corrected version:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Caption}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|} {\textbf{Title1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\textbf{Title2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\textbf{Title3}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{text text text text} & text text text  text  text & text text text text text text text text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & text text text text text & text text text text text text text text text text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text text } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & связях text text text text & text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text }   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ text text text } & text text text & text text text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ text text text } & text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text …} \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|} {text text  texttexttext \par texttexttext} & texttexttext \par texttexttext texttexttexttext & texttexttexttext texttexttexttext \\ \hline
{text text  texttexttext \par texttexttext} & texttexttext \par texttexttext texttexttexttext & texttexttexttext texttexttexttext \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- in your table all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` are superfluous. remove them.
- for column headers use the `\thead` macro from package `makecell`
- for nicer looking of table i would add vertical space around cells' contents with use of `\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \renewcommand\thead{\normalsize\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\theadgape{}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}[htb]
      \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
      \centering
  \caption{Caption}
      \label{tab2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
      \hline
  \thead{Title1}  & \thead{Title2}    & \thead{Title3}                    \\
      \hline
  text text text text
      & text text text text text
          & text text text text text text text text text text             \\
      \hline
  text text text
      & text text text text text
          & text text text text text text text text text text text text   \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text text }                                  \\
      \hline
  text text text
      & text text text text
          & text                                                          \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text text }                                       \\
      \hline
  text text text
      & text text text
          & text text text                                                \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text }                                            \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ text text text }
          & text                                                          \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ text \dots}                                       \\
      \hline
  text text  texttexttext \par
  texttexttext
      & texttexttext \par
        texttexttext texttexttexttext
          & texttexttexttext texttexttexttext                             \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: +1. Out of the question, IMHO also are superfluous all the vertical lines and the third horizontal line, whereas the others should be preferably  `booktabs` rules.

Comment: @Fran, thank you!  i agree with you, however this would change appearance of table, i.e. this would make table more "professional".